# spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka Set manual Offset for consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, offset, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Here, on consuming and processing kafka messages, we are doing some redis operations.Whenever the redis is down or it throws an error/exception we need to persist the offset and when the redis comes up we need to consume the messages from the persisted offset.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `KafkaBindingRebalanceListener` bean.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#rebalance-listener

> Applications may wish to seek topics/partitions to arbitrary offsets when the partitions are initially assigned, or perform other operations on the consumer. Starting with version 2.1, if you provide a single `KafkaBindingRebalanceListener` bean in the application context, it will be wired into all Kafka consumer bindings.

```java
public interface KafkaBindingRebalanceListener {

...
    /**
     * Invoked when partitions are initially assigned or after a rebalance.
     * Applications might only want to perform seek operations on an initial assignment.
     * @param bindingName the name of the binding.
     * @param consumer the consumer.
     * @param partitions the partitions.
     * @param initial true if this is the initial assignment.
     */
    default void onPartitionsAssigned(String bindingName, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions,
            boolean initial) {

    }
}
```

Stop the binding when redis is down and re-start it when it comes back up and perform seeks on the `Consumer`.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control for stopping/starting the binding.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Gary Russell.But i need to continue the consumption of kafka messages, but will skip those redis operations.

Comment: Kafka is not really designed for such use cases, however, the upcoming spring-kafka 2.8 release has a new feature to use the `KafkaTemplate` to receive a single record from a specific topic/partition/offset - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.0-M2/reference/html/#x28-template